# How to control field_group quantity - control field group quantity

Tags: entities

I Cant speak english very well.So sorry if my post is not very good.

When we add a field like text input or file field , we can control number of quantity of thats field.for example if number of a text field set "unlimite",user can click on a button for add another field.

So I want to give possibility to user that after click on "ADD BUTTON" a new field group add to form fields.

If show a table bottom of form (involve added field groups) , this is very good.

example :

```
textfield1     textfield2    textfield3
```

> add button

(**after click this button or submit above fields , another 3 textfields show to me and submitted textfields show bellow on a table**)

Is any module for this work? 
thank you for your response beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank For responses.
I used Filed Group multiple Module for this problem.
[Filed Group multiple](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_multiple)

> This module extends the Field group module by displays and widgets
>   which group multiple fields by there items.

Answer (score 1):

Field group is used for purely cosmetic purposes. If you want to enable the functionality you describe, use [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection).

Comment: thank you.but field_collection **is not covered by Drupal’s security advisory policy.**

Comment: Is another module for field_group?

Comment: Well, like I mentioned Field Group is purely cosmetic. The module you want (security coverage or otherwise) is the one mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I can't understand your last comment ! sorry. I say in the **field_collection module page** this passage is showing and say me warning : ** is not covered by Drupal’s security advisory policy**  . using field_collection module have any security issue?